# Discovering EMC PowerPath LUNs and creating partitions on Solaris

Tags: partition, solaris, hard-disk

I have to work with EMC PowerPath disks/LUNs. I find them in the `/dev/dsk/` directory under names such as `emcpower0a`, `emcpower0b`, …, `emcpower0z`, `emcpower1a`, …

Here are my points of confusion:

- Inside of `/dev/dsk/`, it will the show disks `emcpower##[a-z]` regularly, but when it gets to 'p' (`emcpower#p`), it includes `emcpower#p0`, `emcpower#p1`, …, `emcpower#p4`. Why is it showing me partitions for these and not any others?
- When I try to create partitions on a disk, I do this: `format emcpower0a`; then I go into partition, modify, and assign a size for each of the available slices. I then type `quit`, type `save` at the `format >` prompt, and `exit`. Yet, after that, where do I find these slices?

Comment: 1. look for cfgadm command output; 2. check from emc itself if the disks are showing filesystems.

Comment: `devfsadm -c disk -v` to rescan the disks affter you run cfgadm. Verify it with `fcinfo` and `prtconf` commands.

Comment: Are you running X86 of Sparc?  If SPARC were these Luns ever assigned to a system with a BIOS?

Comment: If this is X86 or if the disk have a BIOS partition table then you must set one of the partitions to have a Solaris ID=BE.  Note: ID 82 is depreciated for sue for Solaris due to it conflicting with Linux Swap.

Answer (score 1):

The p# partitions is an X86 / BIOS thing.

In the Solaris-on-X86 world, Solaris partitions are a little like Extended partitions - the Solaris VTOC and s* partitions lives inside a primary partition.

p0 is the entire disk.
 p1-p4 are the 4 physical partitions recognized by the BIOS.
 s1-15 are the Solaris VTOC partitions (Some of which are special).

Your Solaris type partitions are created in one of these.  The format tool will only access the first partition with a Solaris ID.  fdisk can set a Solaris ID on a physical partition, then run format to create a Solaris vtoc in that partition.

Use the new "BE" ID for Solaris, not the old "82" which is also used for Linux Swap.

Comment: I almost never see links to reference URLs posted on SE so I assume it is not allowed?